# How to form an SQL query that is like using 'IN' across two columns as pairs?

Tags: sql, select

I have two integer columns and I wish to select rows with particular pairings of values.  What SQL syntax can I use?  For example, using `IN` it might look something like this if IN supported this syntax:

```
select * 
 from myTable 
 where value1, value2 in ((2,3), (3,4), (2,5), (3,6))
```

To select those rows with 
`value1 == 2 and value2 == 3 or value1==3 and value2==4 or 2/5 or 3/6`.

I'm using a proprietary SQL system, so basic SQL is preferred.  Or if there is none, having a statement that works in some standard SQL would be useful as well.

Comment: Is your data ((2,3), (3,4), (2,5), (3,6)) coming from table or hard coded?

Comment: @Bobby It is hard coded.

Comment: @Parado It is a proprietary database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select yourtable.* 
from yourtable
     inner join 
     (
          select 2 as v1, 3 as v2 
          union select 3,4
          union select 2,5
          union select 3,6
     ) pairs
         on yourtable.value1 = pairs.v1
         and yourtable.value2 = pairs.v2
```

Answer (score 1):

Well in SQL Server you can't use `IN` that way unfortunately.  I think your best bet is going to be to write it out like you did below your code sample or to load your data into a CTE or something and then joining on that.

Answer (score 1):

same can be achieved by using                `VALUES`

```
select table_name.* 
  from table_name tn, 
       (values(2,3), (3,4), (2,5), (3,6) ) as val(v1,v2) 
  where tn.value1 = val.v1 and tn.value2 = val.v2
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `values` keyword is not implemented in my proprietary DBMS.